# Fail to push local branch on existing repo on github

Tags: git, github, ssh

I tried to push my local branch on github as usual and suddenly it doesn't work.
When I try the  push origin master command I get this error message:

> ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Operation timed out fatal:
> Unable to read the remote repository.
>
> Please check that you have access rights and that the repository
> exists.

and when I try to generate a new key, I am asked if I want to rewrite it because it already exists.

Comment: You have a network connection problem. This has nothing to do with your key. Either there is a problem in your local network that is preventing access to github, a problem at some intermediate point, or github was having a service outage when you attempted to connect.

Answer (score 0):

OMG I had a vpn running. Shame. Thanks @larks